# How to record data while app is not in focus?

Tags: java, android, adb

I've created an app that records data usage of an app and writes it to a file on the phones sd card. Now I'm trying to allow this process to run in the background through the use of adb. I want to be able to send a signal/broadcast to the app to write the current data usage. And later be able to send a second signal that writes the data usage and the new time. So that one can look at how much data the app has used.

So far I've tried using adb and sending broadcasts to the app and it seems to be working however I am not able to save the file to the sd card through the use of mediascanner.

This is the function that is run when I send "adb -d shell am broadcast -n com.axel.datatracking/.IntentReceiver --es --start 'com.linku.android.mobile_emergency.app.activity' " to the app.

```
public void startLog(Context context, SimplifiedAppInfo selectedApp) {
        int i = 0;
        String name = "dataFile.csv";
        Log.d("update", "sort of works maybe");
        // make the file if it already exists increment the name by 1
        try {
            testFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), name);
            while(testFile.exists()) {
                i++;
                name = this.makeFileName(i);
                testFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), name);
            }
            Log.d("filename", name);
            testFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("broke", "Unable to write my dood");
        }
        // try to write to the file
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(testFile);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testFile, true));
            startingDown = selectedApp.getDownbytes();
            startingUp = selectedApp.getUpbyts();
            startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            writer.write("data,up,down\n");
            writer.write("Initial,"+selectedApp.getUpbyts()+","+selectedApp.getDownbytes()+"\n");
            writer.close();
            // refresh the data file
            //MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{this.testFile.toString()}, null, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("broke", "cant write to the file");
        }
    }
```

This is the function to write the end results that is run by "adb -d shell am broadcast -n com.axel.datatracking/.IntentReceiver --es --end 'com.linku.android.mobile_emergency.app.activity' "

```
public void endLog(Context context, SimplifiedAppInfo selectedApp) {
        // write end results to file
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testFile, true));
         writer.write("End,"+selectedApp.getUpbyts()+","+selectedApp.getDownbytes()+"\n");
            float effectiveDown = selectedApp.getDownbytes() - startingDown;
            float effectiveUp = selectedApp.getUpbyts() - startingUp;
            writer.write("Effective,"+effectiveUp+","+effectiveDown+"\n");
            float timePassed = ((float) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime)/1000));
            float avgUp = effectiveUp/timePassed;
            float avgDown = effectiveDown/timePassed;
            writer.write("Average bytes/sec,"+avgUp+","+avgDown+"\n");
            writer.close();
            fOut.close();
            //MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{this.testFile.toString()},null, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("broke", "the write dont work");
        }
    }
```

Broadcast receivers components are not allowed to bind to services.

Edit: I'm open to other solutions besides using a broadcast receiver I just need to be able to log the data while outside of the app and focusing on another app, from the terminal.

Comment: Have you tried to regter Broadcast receiver in manifest and use it as service?

Comment: @AntonisRadz it is already registered in the manifest how would I go about using it as a service?

Comment: See answer below, ant let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Register receiver in manifest and then make some Receiver class, example:

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {  
  @Override
public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
      //// here you can start your own service or do logic here
}
```

here is how to register receiver in Manifest just pick different intent filter:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.example.example.CustomReceiver ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

And `onReceive` going to be called whenever phone action will be triggered.
I would advice to read documentation about Intents because Android has a lot of restrictions, per